# About Decision Tree !

Tags: binary-tree

I want to know that all decision trees are binary Trees?

thanks

Comment: If every decision I ever made had a 50-50% chance of being right, I suspect I'd make the right decision far more often. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're not.  What if the decision is "What is your favourite colour?"  You could have 2 billion answers if you accept 8 bit per channel RGB.

Answer (score 0):

**No. All decision trees are not binary trees.** But, if you really want a binary tree, you can also do it. In fact, the number of branches depends on the nature of data that you are going to classify.

There are two types of data.

**1. Discrete data**

**2. Continuous data**

Suppose `A` be the splitting attribute and `A` has distinct values `{a_1, a_2, ... , a_v}`, based on the training data. Then there are 3 cases.

**CASE 1 : `A`is discrete valued -** a branch is created for each known value of `a_j` in `A`. For example, if `age` is a discrete valued attrribute, it can be branched to `young`, `medium` or `old`.

**CASE 2 : `A` is continuous valued -** the test node has two possible outcomes corresponding to the conditions `A <= split_point` and `A > split_point`, respectively. For example, if `age` is a continuous valued attribute, it can be branched by conditions `age <= 55` and `age > 55`.

**CASE 3 - `A` is a discrete valued and a binary tree must be produced -** the test at the node if of the form of `is A in splitting_subset ?`, where `splitting_subset` is the set of values acceptable in a certain decision out of two decisions. For example, if `age` is a discrete valued attribute, it can be branched by the form of a test of `is age in {young, medium}?`.